# Simple Chonometer VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, stopwatch

I was trying to do a simple chronometer, while Excel was doing some procedures.

Something to the user get looking, showing that excel was working.

I tried to use Time, Date and Timer functions. But the three options made Excel stop responding after 10 seconds. I use 2010 version .

Some code like this:

```
Sub StopWatch()

Dim i As Integer
Dim t1 As Single
Dim t2 As Single

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    t1 = Timer
    i = 0
    Do Until i = 60
        t2 = Timer
        If (t2 - t1) >= 1 Then
            t1 = t2
            i = i + 1
            Range("D4").Value = i
        End If
    Loop
End sub
```

I found some stopwatch's  routines on the net,  but I thought they are very complex.

Is there some way to use any of that three functions, without stopping Excel?

Thanks for  any sugestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it simple; `Application.StatusBar = "Macro running, please wait...."`

Comment: Thanks, Tim, I found another sugestion that worked better for me: [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822851.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub StopWatch()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim t1, t2  As Single
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    t1 = Timer
    i = 0
    Do Until i = 60
        t2 = Timer
        If (t2 - t1) >= 1 Then
            t1 = t2
            i = i + 1
            Range("D4").Value = i
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
End sub
```

Comment: Per [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).